# When does this fourier series converge?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

For which $-2\pi < x < 2\pi$ does this series converge?

$$1 = \sum_n^{\infty} A_n\cos\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right)x\right]$$

The cosine function is piecewise orthogonal.

---

I found

$$A_n = \frac{(1, X_n)}{(X_n,X_n)} = \frac{4(-1)^n}{\pi(2n+1)}$$

which goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ which seems to imply that the series converges for all $x$ in the interval since $\max |X_n|= 1$ (the cosine function) .

Of course it won't always converge to $1$.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Please double check the value of  $(1,X_n)=\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}cos((n+1/2)x)dx$.